# Angular ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_detailsShow' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-datatables

I am having an angular datatables issue with the responsive element set to true.
I am getting the below error on a specific scenario, that follows.

**When no errors:**
[When no errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktnka.png)

**Errors after the server returns empty rows once:**
[Errors after the server returns empty rows once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iZhd.png)

When the page is initialized and there are rows by the default filters, the responsive expand button works fine. But when a custom search is made that returns no rows and then another search happens that returns rows lose the expand event and I get the above error. I am sure this has got something to do with destroying the datatable instance and reinitialize it with the new data from the server.

**Packaged used:**

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "angular-datatables": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.19",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "metismenu": "^3.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng-block-ui": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  }
```

**Code:**

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  OnDestroy,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  LogsService
} from './logs.service';
import {
  Log
} from './log';
import {
  GlobalService
} from '../shared/global.service';
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormBuilder
} from '@angular/forms';
import {
  DataTableDirective
} from 'angular-datatables';
import {
  Subject
} from 'rxjs';
import {
  Filter
} from '../shared/filter';
import {
  BlockUI,
  NgBlockUI
} from 'ng-block-ui';
declare
var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-logs',
  templateUrl: './logs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logs.component.css']
})

export class LogsComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
  dtElement: DataTableDirective;
  dtOptions: any = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject < LogsComponent > = new Subject();
  currentLogs: Log[];
  elements: any;
  filterForm: FormGroup;
  filter: Filter;
  @BlockUI() blockUI: NgBlockUI;

  constructor(private logService: LogsService, private globalService: GlobalService, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentLogs = [];
    this.dtOptions = {
      retrieve: true,
      responsive: true,
      dom: '<l>Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', {
          extend: 'pdfHtml5',
          orientation: 'landscape',
          pageSize: 'TABLOID'
        },
        {
          extend: 'print',
          orientation: 'landscape',
          pageSize: 'TABLOID',
          paperSize: 'TABLOID',
          customize: function(win) {
            $(win.document.body)
              .css('font-size', '10pt');
            $(win.document.body).find('table')
              .addClass('compact')
              .css('font-size', 'inherit');
          }
        }
      ]
    };

    this.filterForm = this.fb.group({
      customer: ['ALL'],
      division: ['ALL'],
      eventCode: ['ALL'],
      statusCode: ['ALL'],
      source: ['ALL'],
      destination: ['ALL'],
      logStart: [''],
      logEnd: ['']
    });

    this.globalService.getUiElementObject(true).subscribe(el => {
      console.log(el);
      this.elements = el;
      this.filterForm = this.fb.group({
        customer: ['ALL'],
        division: ['ALL'],
        eventCode: ['ALL'],
        statusCode: 'All',
        source: ['ALL'],
        destination: ['ALL'],
        logStart: [this.elements.logStart],
        logEnd: [this.elements.logEnd],
      });

      this.applyFilter(false);
    }, error => console.log(error));
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.reloadUIFeatures();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }

  applyFilter(datecheck) {
    this.blockUI.start();

    if (datecheck) {
      this.filterForm.patchValue({
        logStart: $("#dtStartDate").val(),
        logEnd: $("#dtEndDate").val()
      });
    }

    const fil = { ...this.filter,
      ...this.filterForm.value
    };
    this.logService.getLogs(fil).subscribe(logs => {
      var previousCount = 0;
      var currentCount = 0;

      if (this.currentLogs) {
        previousCount = this.currentLogs.length;
      }

      this.currentLogs = logs;
      this.reloadUIFeatures();
      currentCount = this.currentLogs.length;

      if (this.dtElement.dtInstance) {
        this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
          dtInstance.destroy(); // 1) Suspected error zone
        });
      }

      this.dtTrigger.next(); // 2) Suspected error zone

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.blockUI.stop();
      }, 2000);
    }, error => console.log(error));
  }

  reloadUIFeatures() {
    var dtStDt = $("#dtStartDate").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
    var dtEdDt = $("#dtEndDate").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h1 class="page-header">Event Logs</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <form novalidate autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="applyFilter(true)" [formGroup]="filterForm" class="panel-heading">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4>Filter by</h4>
            <div>
              <div class="">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label" attr.for="lstCustomer">Customer</label>
                      <div>
                        <select class="form-control" id="lstCustomer" *ngIf="elements" formControlName="customer">
                          <option *ngFor='let cu of elements.customerList' value="{{ cu.key }}">{{ cu.value }}</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label" attr.for="lstSource">Source</label>
                      <div>
                        <select class="form-control" id="lstSource" *ngIf="elements" formControlName="source">
                          <option *ngFor='let cu of elements.sourceList' value="{{ cu.key }}">{{ cu.value }}</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <div style="">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" attr.for="lstDivisionNo">Division</label>
                        <div>
                          <select class="form-control" id="lstDivisionNo" *ngIf="elements" formControlName="division">
                            <option *ngFor='let cu of elements.opcoList' value="{{ cu.key }}">{{ cu.value }}</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" attr.for="lstDestination">Destination</label>
                        <div>
                          <select class="form-control" id="lstDestination" *ngIf="elements" formControlName="destination">
                            <option *ngFor='let cu of elements.destinationList' value="{{ cu.key }}">{{ cu.value }}</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <div style="">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" attr.for="lstEventCode">Event Code</label>
                        <div>
                          <select class="form-control" id="lstEventCode" *ngIf="elements" formControlName="eventCode">
                            <option *ngFor='let cu of elements.eventCodeList' value="{{ cu.key }}">{{ cu.value }}</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" attr.for="dtStartDate">Log Date</label>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <input class="form-control" style="" type="text" id="dtStartDate" formControlName="logStart">
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <input class="form-control" style="" type="text" id="dtEndDate" formControlName="logEnd">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <div style="">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" attr.for="lstStatusCode">Status Code</label>
                        <div>
                          <select class="form-control" id="lstStatusCode" *ngIf="elements" formControlName="statusCode">
                            <option *ngFor='let cu of elements.statusCodeList' value="{{ cu }}">{{ cu }}</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" attr.for="lstStatusCode">&nbsp;</label>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary form-control">Apply</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-body">
          <block-ui>
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dtEventLogs" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Customer</th>
                    <th class="minWidth-s4">Log Entry Date</th>
                    <th>Status Table</th>
                    <th>Status Key</th>
                    <th>Status Code</th>
                    <th class="minWidth-s4">Attempt Made At</th>
                    <th>Applied?</th>
                    <th class="minWidth-s4">Last Updated</th>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th class="minWidth-s1">Cntr No</th>
                    <th>Event Code</th>
                    <th>Division</th>
                    <th>Status Field</th>
                    <th>Update Table</th>
                    <th>Update Field</th>
                    <th>Update Field Type</th>
                    <th>Update Value</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="even gradeA" *ngFor='let log of currentLogs'>
                    <td class="details-control">{{log.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.customerNo}}</td>
                    <td class="minWidth-s4">{{log.logEntryDate | date:'medium'}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.statusTableName}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.statusTableId}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.statusCode}}</td>
                    <td class="minWidth-s4">{{log.attemptedUpdateDate | date:'medium'}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.apply}}</td>
                    <td class="minWidth-s4">{{log.lastUpdated | date:'medium'}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.updatedBy}}</td>
                    <td class="minWidth-s1">{{log.containerNumber}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.eventCode}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.divisionNumber}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.statusFieldName}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.updateTableName}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.updateFieldName}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.updateFieldType}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.updateFieldValue}}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </block-ui>
          <!-- /.table-responsive -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-body -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.panel -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated. This sure is a school boy error on initialising/destroying/re-creating the data table instance the angular way.

Regards,

Ram

Comment: Hello, you are right, re-creating datatable make it loose event that were creating when loading page. Take a look here: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/events_pre_init.html
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html

Comment: Just initialize currentLogs variable on ngOnInit() i.e. `ngOnInit(){ currentLogs = []; ...... }`

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. Still no joy after initializing currentLogs in ngOnInit().

Comment: This could (without knowing more) have something to do with versions. "_etc" variables are generally private; you're not supposed to be trying to read them. Something here is trying to read such a variable, but the object that it exists on is no longer available. One possibility is that some developer decided to read that private var anyway, some version of something somewhere changed, and of course that version does not check for backward compatibility of variables you're not supposed to be reading in the first place.

Comment: I did a hack on the jquery.dataTables.js file to handle the nulls correctly and it worked. It is a hack around which is not ideal but works for now. I am keeping it open so I can fix it properly soon. The main error so far is that 'aoData' element is duplicated after the 'dtInstance' is destroyed and recreated.